# One sided limit and its value

Tags: analysis

Use the concept of one-sided limits to show that f (x) = x[[x]] has a limit as x approaches 0. What is the value of the limit?

Comment: Is $[x]$ rounding? What have you tried?

Comment: $[[x]]$ means integral part of $x$.

Comment: [[x]] stands for greatest integer, im totally confused right now :(

Comment: the problem is the same as this one but dont know where to start, badly need help right now, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114512/limit-of-a-greatest-integer-function

Comment: Hint: $[[x]]$ does not change value in, say, $[0,1)$.

Comment: can you give me additional problems the same as above with solution, it will be a big help for me right now

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$\lfloor x\rfloor = x - h$, where $h \in [0,1)$.

So, $f (x) = x(x-h)$ for some $h \in [0,1)$.

Now, apply the limits.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ approaches zero from the left, $x \to 0$, and $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \to -1$, hence
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} x\lfloor{x}\rfloor = (0)(-1) = 0$$
As $x$ approaches zero from the right, $x \to 0$, and $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \to 0$, hence
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x\lfloor{x}\rfloor = (0)(0) = 0$$

It follows that ${\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0} x\lfloor{x}\rfloor = 0}}$.