# How to solve this limit of greatest integer function (floor function)?

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to calculate this limit $?$ :

$$
\lim_{x\ \to\ 0^{+}}\,\,\,\frac{x}{a}
\left\lfloor\,{\frac{b}{x}}\,\right\rfloor\,,\qquad a, b > 0
$$
where $\left\lfloor\,{x}\,\right\rfloor$ represents $greatest\ integer\ function$ or floor function, i.e greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Use the fact that $y-1 < \lfloor y \rfloor \le y$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of a greatest integer function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114512/limit-of-a-greatest-integer-function)

Comment: @AnneBauval, unfortunately, it does not.  Because my question has two variables and two fractions.

Comment: Of course it does! $y:=\frac xb\to0^+$ and $\frac{x}{a}\left\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\right\rfloor=\frac bay\left\lfloor\frac1y\right\rfloor.$

Answer (score 0):

We can start off by substituting $\frac{b}{x}$
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{a}\left\lfloor \frac{b}{x} \right\rfloor=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{bx}{a}\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor=\frac{b}{a}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}$$
Intuitively, the limit on the right-hand side approaches 1 because the difference between $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ becomes negligible as $x$ approaches infinity, but we can prove it using algebra
$$L=\frac{b}{a}\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\frac{x-[x]}{x}=\frac{b}{a}\left(1-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[x]}{x}\right)$$
where [x] is the fractional part of x

The fractional part of x, [x], has a range $0≤y≤1$, so we can use the squeeze theorem. Keep in mind we can prove this using the exact same methods for $x\rightarrow -\infty$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{0}{x}≤\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[x]}{x}≤\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x}$$
$$0≤\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[x]}{x}≤0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[x]}{x}=0$$
Plugging it back in we get
$$L=\frac{b}{a}\left(1-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[x]}{x}\right)=\frac{b}{a}(1-0)=\frac{b}{a}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{a}\left\lfloor \frac{b}{x} \right\rfloor=\frac{b}{a}$$

Comment: $x = n + r,\quad n \in \mathbb{N},\quad r \in \left[0,1\right)$. Then,
$$
{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \over x} = {1 \over 1 + r/n}
$$

Comment: @phi-rate, so if  x tends minus infinity, then is it 1 as well?

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}$ tends to 1 as well with the same logic, and I updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: @phi-rate, so if the limit of the question has x tending to -0, is the final result b/a as well?